# Where do I find information where I can download the legislative mapping data

Tags: data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where I can download legislative mapping data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13906/where-i-can-download-legislative-mapping-data)

It is a collection of files downloaded from aristotle to map Zip to District data. 
Among the files are
1.  Census Code (ILCENSUS) which has County Census Code, State Census Code and State County Name
2.  Legislator Identification (IL105ZD) which has district address information, legislator number and name.
3.  Legislative district mapping(ILLEGYY) which has County Code, State Census Code and  Zip.

Comment: is this a clarification of your previous question? (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13906/where-i-can-download-legislative-mapping-data)  If so, you can edit that question to include this info.